# Stable Distribution Log-likelihood and AIC values

Tags: r, parameters, statistics, distribution, data-fitting

I have used the `stableFit` function from the `fBasics` package to come up with parameters (alpha, beta, gamma, and delta) for a stable distribution as you can see below:

```
stableFit(x)
```

I then did the following to come up with log likelihood values and for some reason, it doesn't seem to work:

```
stable.fit <- function(alpha=1.387,beta=0.279,
                       gamma=0.006948893,delta=-0.0017933) {
   -sum(dstable(x,1.387,0.279,0.006948893,-0.0017933,pm=0,log=TRUE))
}


mle.results<-mle2(stable.fit,
         start=list(alpha=1.387,beta=0.279,
                   gamma=0.006948893,delta=-0.0017933),
   data=list(x)) #max likelihood using bbmle package

mle.results #produces the log-likelihood values
```

It seems that when I run the `mle.results<- mle2(..` line, R is continuously running and will not stop until I press the "STOP" button. Because of this, I am unable to then ask for the "mle.results". Why is this happening? This process seems to work fine for the Normal, logistic, Cauchy, Student t, skewed Student t, Gumbell and generalized extreme value distributions.

Please let me know what I am missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I created a new package based on old package **[stable](https://github.com/cran/stable)** by Lambert and Lindsey that didn't really work. But it uses FFT of the characteristic function and has the core code in C. I polished it and wrote some wrappers around it. so density and probability is based on that, then in my package, random draws and quantiles are from the **stabledist** package as they work fast enough.

So it provides faster alternative to *fBasics::stableFit* with minimal loss of accuracy compared to them and is about 140x faster. It is available [**here**](https://github.com/jansila/jStable). I will finalise it completely soon.

In the meantime: **Dataset**:

```
require(tawny)
data("sp500.subset")
rnorm<-rnorm(200)
rt<-rt(200,4)
cauch<-rcauchy(200)
testingData<-matrix(cbind(rnorm,rt,cauch,as.matrix(sp500.subset,nrow=200)),nrow=200)
```

Those are differences of my coefficients to the **fBasics** ones.You can see that only beta estimates differ quite a lot to *fBasics::stableFit* ones (beta is between -1 and 1) but it doesnt really have a large effect. I will try to dig up some literature as well.

[image: coefficients]

Here are densities for the series with 16 largest beta differences. Blue are my densities using and red are *stabledist::dstable* densities which fBasics uses for the MLE optimisation. Circles are based on coefficients from fBasics optimisation and crosses are mine.

[image: densities]

I included the test script in the [depository](https://github.com/jansila/jStable/blob/master/testScript.R) as well. 
And last but not least is the speed comparison:

[image]

Comment: although OP didn't give a reproducible example, it would be useful if you did (and showed benchmarks)

Comment: Good idea, I have some time and estimates comparisons..will edit them with my answer then :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I was able to answer my own question. The problem was that R took a lot longer to got through the `mle2` calculation along with the integration of the `dstable` function. Log-likelihood results took less than 10 seconds for the other distributions but for some reason, it took over 45 minutes!! for the stable distribution. I only figured this out after I decided to just let it run while I worked on other things and after 45-50 minutes, it finished. However, I can't figure out why the stable distribution is taking exceptionally long to do this calculation. Anyway, problem solved.